# How to understand the IPv6 route table

Tags: routing, ipv6

Here is the `ip -6 route` result of my working OpenWRT system.  I find that this is quite different to the route table of ipv4.

```
    default from :: via fe80::3e8a:b0ff:fe86:f870 dev eth0.2  proto static  metric 1024
    default from 2402:f000:5:8401::/64 via fe80::3e8a:b0ff:fe86:f870 dev eth0.2  proto static  metric 1024
    default from fc00:101:101::/64 via fe80::3e8a:b0ff:fe86:f870 dev eth0.2  proto static  metric 1024
    2402:f000:5:8401::/64 dev eth0.2  proto static  metric 256
    fc00:101:101::/64 dev br-lan  proto kernel  metric 256
    fda0:52f6:20cb::/64 dev br-lan  proto static  metric 1024
    fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
    fe80::/64 dev eth0.2  proto kernel  metric 256
    fe80::/64 dev br-lan  proto kernel  metric 256
    fe80::/64 dev wlan1  proto kernel  metric 256
    fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

First, why IPv6 has multiple default routing entries?  Second, I found that all the ipv6 routing entries do not specify the source IP of the interface (in ipv4, the route table has a column like `src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`).

Comment: openwrt is off topic

Comment: @MikePennington - Why is openwrt offtopic?  I see nothing about the system that precludes its use in a profesional environment per se.  Yes, it's strictly an OS for low-end equipment, but wouldn't you say there's still a place for such equipment in appropriate circumstances?

Comment: @jules you may make a case in meta... but this has been discussed several times and the consensus is not supporting openwrt on this site.  Superuser.com is always an option

Comment: @MikePennington This question really had nothing to do with OpenWRT and should not have been closed.  Please re-read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's explain the address prefixes:

**fe80::/10** - Link Local

**2000::/3**  -  global Unicast (2402:f000:5:8401::/64 in your example)

**fc00::/7**  - unique local (RFC4193) (fc00:101:101::/64 and  fda0:52f6:20cb::/64 in your example)

Link-Local addresses are valid on the link olny (e.g. the VLAN your are currently connected to), global unicast is globally reachable (at least if there is no firewall / acl blocking traffic) and unique-local addresses  globally unique (at least in theory) and used for local communications and not routed on the internet

An interface has always one link-local address and can have one or more global addresses.

You see a route for each of these prefix types (first three lines)

An address from 2402:f000:5:8401::/64 is assigned to eht0.2 and fc00:101:101::/64 / fda0:52f6:20cb::/64 to your br-lan interface.

Thr rest are the link-local entries for the different interfaces.

Comment: While fc00::/7 is is the unique local unicast address range, one point is that addresses with the L bit not set (fc00::/8) are not currently defined, while addresses with the L bit set (fd00::/8) should be assigned with a randomly generated global ID to reduce the odds of duplicate networks. The unique local address that the OP is using is currently undefined.

Comment: "*depreciated*", but still valid. (which is true of *a lot* of IPv6 things. 20 years on, and we still haven't made a protocol out of)

Comment: @Ricky Beam, of the 17 browser tabs (all Internet web sites) I currently have open, five are connected via IPv6. Ironically, all the technology web sites I'm connected to are IPv4-only.

Comment: Not to derail the topic, but when was the last time there was a fundamental change to IPv4? Decades? IPv6? Last week. Can you get places with v6? Sure. Is your v6 stack current? almost certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

> why [does] IPv6 has multiple default routing entries?

Simple. You have three (3) prefixes -- a "/0" (traditional default), and two "/64"s.  IPv6 supports multiple routers (and thus prefixes) per interface. In this case, they do all go to the same place.